# How to check remote GIT repository permission without commit/add any files or modify any files

Tags: git, github, permissions, gitlab, push

I'm trying to find remote GIT repository permission without any file changes.
I have tried below command,

```
"git push --dry-run"
```

its shows, everything-up-to-date.

The problem is I have cloned my remote repository after that I removed all my permission in remote git repository I want to know the remote repository permission before any local changes I made.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can at least check if the remote repo is still remotely readable with [`git ls-remote`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-remote)

From any folder in your local machine, type `git ls-remote /url/remote/repo`.

But for any more advance permission check, you would need to go to the remote server hosting that repo.

Or at list query that server, listing the members for a given project.
See [GitLab API "List all members of a group or project"](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/members.html#list-all-members-of-a-group-or-project).
Each member has access_level which will give a fined-grained permission.

```
10 => Guest access
20 => Reporter access
30 => Developer access
40 => Maintainer access
50 => Owner access # Only valid for groups
```

---

Note that [GitLab 15.1](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/06/22/gitlab-15-1-released/#api-includes-additional-detail-about-who-added-members) (June 2022) adds:

> ### API includes additional detail about who added members
>
> The members API now returns more information about who added a user to a project or group in the new `created_by` field.
>
> Thank you [Rémy Jacquin](https://gitlab.com/remyj38) for your contribution!
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/members.html) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/28789).

Comment: Thanks, for helping,we are using with LDAP group for around 100 people, for the particular remote repository everybody has R- READ permission, i want to verify remote repository permission without "go to the remote server hosting and verify repo" more like i need result in terminal itself.

Comment: @vinoth You still need to query the server somehow, and list the project members. I have edited the answer accordingly. The result will be displayed "in the terminal itself".

Comment: thank you. i was looking for any GIT commands to verify the remote repository permission. anyhow at-last we are going to use API calls only.

Comment: @vinoth Yes, good move: Git itself knows nothing about permission. Only the remote Git repositories hosting server knows about said permission, hence the API calls. GitLab is not Git.

Comment: yeah, i knew that we are using same as like gitlab its called gitblit